# How did this happen?

Tags: bug, profile-page, views

So recently I looked at a user's profile. However, its profile view count was 0.[image]

So how did this happen? Since I'm logged in shouldn't it be at least 1?

Comment: Caching. It's always caching.

Comment: You're a ghost. We... didn't want to tell you.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not a ghost, I'm a cat!

Comment: @UniKitty Those aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: what a *cat*astrophe